# Can you set up a hyperlink in a GIF made in photoshop? - Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

Just wondering if you are able to add a hyperlink to a gif through photoshop? I created an email signature in photoshop and there is a website the client wants set up as a hyperlink if you click on it in their email signature.

[image]

Comment: No. A gif is simply an image file. It can't have clickable links embedded in the GIF file itself. It's not possible.  You may be able to make the gif a clickable link in your email software however,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not on the GIF directly, there's no such thing as having clickable links embedded in GIF.

However, since that's an email signature, you can probably set up the link on top of the image in some email apps (eg. in Outlook you can do [this](https://youtu.be/9WsAhHbGOxI)).

Answer (score 1):

To specifically answer the question, although other's already have, **no**. A GIF is a raster image, nothing more. Raster web images can not contain embedded hyperlinks. Hyperlinks must be added to *surrounding HTML* which encompasses the image itself.

SVG images *can* contain embedded hyperlinks.. whether or not SVG images are supported in any particular *[email client](https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-svg/)* is an *entirely* different matter. Since Google (Gmail) does *not* support SVG images at this time... to me, it's foolish to try and get SVG images to work in any email.

---

I realize this may be a "client request", but **using an image as an "email signature" is a bad idea**... using an *animated* image is an even worse idea. Alas, if the client *really* wants it, yeah.. you may have to do it. Regardless of how bad the idea is.

> **What not to include in email signatures**
>
> 1. Unnecessary contact information
> 2. Custom fonts
> 3. Bullet points
> 4. **Animated GIFs**
> 5. Videos
> 6. Quotes
> 7. Personal information
> 8. Multiple color fonts
> 9. **An image as your email signature**
> 10. Links to unused accounts or old posts
> 11. Out-of-date promotional banners
> 12. Too many social media icons
> 13. Pointless certifications
> 14. Too much content
> 15. Large image files

> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

> ##### Read the [**Full Article**](https://www.exclaimer.com/email-signature-handbook/what-not-to-include-in-email-signatures/) at exclaimer.com for detailed reasonings/explanations.

###### Regarding emails as *communication* - not sales vehicles

Just offhand.. I'd ask... **how** is anyone going to be able to copy and paste the contact information for use? Answer: They can't. They will have to *retype* it.. *hopefully* they retype it correctly, if they even bother, once they realize they must.

And *that* particular signature image... will reduce to unreadable size for something like a mobile device.

---

For me, I view all emails as **plain text**. *Anything* that is *not* viewable as "plain text" is - 99.99999% of the time - nothing more than unwanted advertising (spam/junk).

If a client of mine has an image as an email signature, each and *every* email they send me has an attachment (the signature). I can't see the image unless I open the attachment (image). And because *every* email has an attachment, I can't tell at a glance when they are *actually* sending attachments which may be important. Or if that little paperclip is just once again noting the attached signature image.

In terms of archiving and retrieval.... I have to actually look at **every** email they've sent should I need to find some specific attachment at a later date - because *every* email has an attachment.

It's a pet peeve of mine... an image "signature" is nothing more than an arrogant annoyance and *detrimental* to how the emails are perceived. Having an email signature image **never** creates *any* favorable opinion or sentiment. In fact, eventually, I start to resent getting the image-signature emails.

<sub>(.... much of this also applies to v-card attachments in *every* email. A v-card is only necessary *once*.)</sub>

---

Create a clear, well crafted, *text only*, email signature. That's all that is necessary. This allows links to be clicked, information to be copied, and doesn't litter emails with unnecessary repetitive attachments.

Your, or the client's, logo is **not** warranted as a signature for **communication** emails. Images and logos are for **sales/marketing** emails.

**Form v Function**: If the *function* is to *communicate*, don't unnecessarily over-complicate the form by adding images unrelated to the *communication*.

---

Answer (score 0):

No. A gif is simply an image file format. It can't have clickable links embedded in the GIF file itself. It's not possible.

However, you may be able to make the gif a clickable link in your email software.

A word of warning: many people have their email clients set up to prohibit the display of images. It's often viewed as a security risk. This is often company policy. That means that many people will not see the image in your email, nor will they be able to click on the link.  You should really included a simple text link if you want everybody to see it and to be able to click on it.